# How to make a checkbox from a list and get selected values in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, checkboxlist

I want to get this result in jupiter notebook:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PU8UL.png)

I tried the Tkinter and ipywidgets library, but nothing works for me

Answer (score 0):

this is bad code, but it works and I don’t have time to write better:

```
list_check = ['check1', 'check2', 'check3', 'check4']

from tkinter import *
class Checkbar(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, picks=[], side=LEFT, anchor=W):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.vars = []
        for pick in picks:
            var = BooleanVar()
            chk = Checkbutton(self, text=pick, variable=var)
            chk.pack(side=side, anchor=anchor, expand=YES)
            self.vars.append(var)
    def state(self):
        return map((lambda var: var.get()), self.vars)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    lng = Checkbar(root, list_check)
    #tgl = Checkbar(root, ['English','German'])
    lng.pack(side=TOP,  fill=X)
    #tgl.pack(side=LEFT)
    lng.config(relief=GROOVE, bd=2)


    def allstates():
        print(list(lng.state()))
       #return bool_check_list

    Button(root, text='Peek', command=allstates).pack(side=RIGHT)
    root.mainloop()

for i in range(len(list(lng.state()))):
    if list(lng.state())[i]==True:
        print(list_check[i])
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiAtb.png)